# Print module's default setting is annoying

Tags: 7, files

We often use the [print module](http://drupal.org/project/print) to create PDF of nodes; most of the times, it works out-of-box.
For our requirements, however, one thing that makes me very annoyed is its default settings.

When the print module is installed, the "Print friendly page" option is enabled for all the available content types, even though it is required only for a few content types. Every time I have to disable it manually by editing the individual content type edit tab form.

Is there a global option I can use to disable the option for all the content types, and enable it for the content types I really need it?
Does this way works for everyone, or did I miss anything?

Comment: There is this related bug in the module issues: https://www.drupal.org/project/print/issues/2842434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--print--print.module/function/print_form_alter/6, it seems to use a constant called PRINT_TYPE_SHOW_LINK_DEFAULT for the default value. That in turn is hardcoded to 1, see http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--print--print.module/constant/PRINT_TYPE_SHOW_LINK_DEFAULT/6.

So you don't have a way to change that without hacking the module.

You could try to submit a feature request in the issue queue: http://drupal.org/project/issues/print